# Deidentification using FPE Primitive Transform and ignoring certain characters

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dlp

is there a way to have the de-identify DLP ignore certain characters? Currently, encrypting EMails with a custom alphabet that includes the "-" sign ends up encrypting as below. Ideally the encrypted text would all be of the format "XXX-XX-XXXX" I noticed there was a CharsToIgnore call that could be made but not sure where to put that... maybe metadata field in the API that's called (deidentify_content?) or at some other place.

Thanks!

- 325-7959452
- 31424943-6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Officially you should reconsider using FPE as it isn't considered the best option by security standards. Only use it if you are in legacy system that is going to be strict about formatting, otherwise deterministic crypto is much better for emails, another technique available in the API will give you better control.

But as for FPE, there is not the ability to skip characters when using FPE, that feature only exists for masking.